# select all columns, simultaneously doing a ifnull on one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to do a select on all columns, displaying a 0 (for a few of them) if null, without having to write each of the columns' names in the statement.

All I could think of is something like this:

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(`nullable_col1`, 0) FROM `my_table`;
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Come on lazybones ;-)

Comment: Laziness is bliss! :)

Comment: Yes, it is. But note that problems of this kind are often symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** there is no way. You have to use the `IFNULL` function on each column which you want to have the value for.

One thing which you can do is that, you can simply select the value for all the columns which are not NULL(*but I am not sure if that is what you want*)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (nullable_col1 AND nullable_col2 AND nullable_col2) IS NOT NULL
```

So this will select only columns which are not NULL.